# Passing object to a function as an argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

I am trying to pass an object to a function but when I try to output the object it says "undefined". Here is an example:

```
// object defined
this.object = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  //some store properties
});

// printing object
function printObject (obj) {
   alert(obj); // my output is "undefined"
}

// trying to pass the object
printObject(this.object);
```

Can anyone tell me how can I pass an object as an argument? thanks in advance

Comment: You have a scoping issue. You need to show more code in order that we can help you see what is wrong. Also, I suspect there will be issues naming any property or variable `object`

Comment: What if you alert this.obejct right after assigning it? Maybe it gets never assigned a value at all. Passing an object to a function this way is very possible,

Comment: Show the properties that the object contains

Answer (score 1):

what is the context here, what does this refer to, another object? try calling it something other than 'object', perhaps 'data'. not 100% sure, but I think 'object' may be reserved.

Answer (score 0):

possibly it is the function `pringObject` (rather than `printObject`) that is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  //some store properties
});
```

So that obj is implicitly casted to an object of type returned by JsonStore